# wpf ObservableCollection fill combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, observablecollection

How do I fill up my combobox to an item of my ObservableCollectio ?

```
public ObservableCollection<Contacts> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>();
```

Item within Contacts is "Grname". Those items need to be binded to it. Prefer by code, because I want to filter out the duplicates (grouping).

```
    class Contacts
{
    public string Contact_id { get; set; }
    public string Grname { get; set; }

}
```

UPDATE:

I found it !

```
ICollectionView contactsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.ItemsSource);

cmbGroup.ItemsSource = contactsView.Groups;
```

But how to filter my datagrid with the selected item of combobox ?

I've got:

```
    void Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {

        if (cmbGroup.ItemsSource == contactsView)
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
    e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

And Filter is binded in CollectionViewSource in my XAML

Answer (score 0):

For filtering, grouping, sorting etc. you could use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613527.aspx). That means something like

```
ICollectionView contactsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(contacts);
// For filtering:
contactsView.Filter += sender => {
    // Filter logic here
    return true;
}
```

Then you bind your combobox against the contactsView.

Comment: @keno If you could more specific what you have tried or what does not work, maybe I can elaborate my example a bit.

Comment: thanks for taking a look ! I found a solution anyway ;) But howto filter my grid ? (see topic)